# In Magento, How does one modify the admin store select list at the search filter stage and not the select stage?

Tags: magento

Magento Admin has a store select drop down list of all the stores.
I have added an addititional "SELECT ALL STORES" value to allow me to know when a user wishes to carry out a task on all stores.

I based this customisation on enterprise magento version 1.9 although I think the version is quite irrelevant since my question is quite generic to magento I think.

How do I stop my  "SELECT ALL STORES" from being selected by default in the search ?

> /index.php/admin/admin/urlrewrite/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store list select form is built here:

app\code\core\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Store.php

Once I found that, I could override it to the local code pool and make the modifications I needed.

```
public function getHtml()
{
    $storeModel = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store');
    /* @var $storeModel Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Store */
    $websiteCollection = $storeModel->getWebsiteCollection();
    $groupCollection = $storeModel->getGroupCollection();
    $storeCollection = $storeModel->getStoreCollection();

    $allShow = $this->getColumn()->getStoreAll();

    $html  = '<select name="' . $this->_getHtmlName() . '" ' . $this->getColumn()->getValidateClass() . '>';
    $value = $this->getColumn()->getValue();
    //if ($allShow) {
        $html .= '<option value=""' . (**$value == 0** ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('All Store Views') . '</option>';
    //} else {
     //   $html .= '<option value=""' . (!$value ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '></option>';
    //}
```

Comment: How can i set default store in magento 2? can you please guide me?